# Zend_Console_Getopt and application envoirment - how to setupt APP_ENV with param?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a problem now with building a mechanism that allows to build console scripts with zend for app. For example like:

--scripts

----index.php

----basecmd.php

When basecmd contains main class for other scripts, and file structure is

```
include index.php
....
MyClass extends Zend_Console_Getopt{
```

but in index.php i need to setup APPLICATION_ENVOIRMENT with param send as --application_env to script
My problem is that I can set it when parsing params with getopt, but how to make it in index.php?
Info: I need to show error like:
'application_env must me always set when running script'
I'd appreciate any guides for doing it.

Comment: can you explain in more details? I have a real hard time understanding what you are trying to do - perhaps some more code snippet. Do you try to use this to run your index.php via web and cli, or to run basecmd.php via web and cli?

Comment: running through cli, i want to make base script that i will include in my all classes i add in ../scripts folder eg. for migrations mechanism or db imports scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you are trying to run your application from CLI/CMD, by calling basecmd.php that will setup variables/constants for index.php to work correctly

Your basecmd.php should look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
// basecmd.php
require_once 'path/to/Zend/Console/Getopt.php';
try {
    $opts = new Zend_Console_Getopt(
        array(
            'app-env|e=s' => 'Application environment',
            'app-path|ap=s' => 'Path to application folder',
            'lib-path|lp=s' => 'Path to library',
            // more options
        )
    );
    $opts->parse();
    if (!($path = $opts->getOption('ap'))) { // cli param is missing
        throw new Exception("You must specify application path");
    }
    define('APPLICATION_PATH', $path);
    // process other params and setup more constants/variables
} catch (Zend_Console_Getopt_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getUsageMessage();
    exit;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
}
// it is wise to setup another constant so application can determine is it a web or cli call
define('RUN_VIA', 'cli');
// if all done correctly include application loader script
include 'index.php';
```

And in your index.php you should just test if constants or variables are already defined:

```
<?php
// index.php
defined('APPLICATION_PATH') // is it defined
    or define('APPLICATION_PATH', '../application'); // no? then define it
defined('RUN_VIA')
    or define('RUN_VIA', 'web');
// ... rest of the code
```

I hope this helps you get on the track ;)